# Rotational invariance of PPCA

Tags: pca, terminology, factor-analysis

From [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/csc2515/notes/lec7middle.pdf) (slide 23) and [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/csc412-2004/notes/lec10x.pdf) (page 5, 4th slide) I understand that it is said that PPCA (probabilistic PCA) is rotational invariant. It can be written as follows:

$$\text{PPCA}(X) = [\mu, W, \sigma^2]$$

$$\text{PPCA}(XQ) = [Q\mu, QW, \sigma^2]$$

where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $X$ is the dataset.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_invariance), a function $f$ is called rotational invariant if $f(Qx)=f(x),\forall x$.

So, if we want PPCA to be rotational invariant, didn't we have to impose that $\text{PPCA}(XQ) = [\mu, W, \sigma^2]$ (i.e. $Q$ to disappear from the returned vector of parameters)?

Or is there some other definition of rotational invariance?

Comment: Where in these slides do you see it stated that PPCA is "rotational invariant"? On p. 23 I see "In PPCA, the data can be rotated without changing anything".

Comment: They probably mean it in the sense of rotationally *covariant.*

Comment: @amoeba Yes, you are right. I kind of combined in my mind the slides above and the slides [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/csc412-2004/notes/lec10x.pdf) - page 5, fourth slide. Here, PCA is said to be rotational invariant, but then the parameters from PPCA come into play (so I believe it is about PPCA being rotational invariant).

Comment: @whuber What does that mean?

Comment: Exactly what you stated in your question.  The language comes from physics, as in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CovariantTensor.html.

Comment: @whuber Just to be sure. The *what you stated in your question* is $f(Rx)=\text{constant}f(x)\text{constant}$?

Comment: That's not it.  "PPCA" is a function $f:X\to Y$ where both $X$ and $Y$ are acted on by a group $G$ (the orthogonal group). For $g\in G$ and $a\in X$ or $a\in Y$ write $a^g$ for the effect of the action of $g$ on $a.$ Then $f$ is *covariant* when $f(x^g)=f(x)^g$ for all $x\in X$ and $g\in G.$

Comment: @whuber But $\sigma$ stays the same. Is it ok to still call it *covariant*? From your comment I understand it should be $Q\sigma^2$.

Comment: One chooses the group action corresponding to the problem.  In this case, the space $Y$ consists of ordered triples $(\mu,W,\sigma^2).$ The orthogonal group acts on it by sending $(\mu,W,\sigma^2)$ to $(Q\mu, QW, \sigma^2).$